# Unable to use Google Calendar API in Meteor - OAuth problems?

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm working on a web app that uses the Google Calendar API (for now, I just want to be able to retrieve and display a list of events from a calendar), but I haven't been able to properly make the API call. Technically, it is made, but I don't get a response since I'm not authenticated. I know I need OAuth credentials, but I'm not sure where exactly to set those up (I already have my client id and secret).

Here is my code, in `body.js`:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

import './body.html';

Template.body.helpers({
    test() {
        HTTP.get("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/michelleran707@gmail.com/events", function(error, response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    },
});
```

And in `body.html`, I call `test` in a random place using `{{test}}`. (I'm not sure if this is correct code, since I'm new to Meteor.)

As for OAuth, I searched around and this was the code I ended up using:

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
  service: "google"
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: "google",
  clientId: "my id",
  secret: "my secret"
});
```

Both of these JavaScript files I've imported into `main.js`. However, I'm still unable to properly make the API call. What am I missing?

Comment: You definitely need auth. But first - you can't make sync HTTP calls from the client. So your should put you `console.log` in async callback.

Comment: Alright, fixed that. Now the problem seems to be actually coming from OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - I tinkered with the code from the official [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) and got the OAuth working. Seems like I just overlooked that in the beginning.